# The difference between Context API and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to find the differences between React Context API and Redux.
The blogs say the difference between them as follows.
Context API prompts a re-render on each update of the state and re-renders all components regardless.
Redux, however, only re-renders the updated components.
I've built the test project and I've found that Context API re-renders only components that are rendered from within the Consumer.
But I don't understand about it.
I think that the principles of them are the same and I can't find the differences in the code.
I'd like to know why Context API re-renders the components theoretically.

Comment: Are you asking about the theoretical difference (between their principles) or about the practical difference (between their implementations)?

Comment: "*I can't find the differences in the code*" - what code in particular did you look at? Can you show us the code you've written, or link the library source code that you've seen?

Comment: Yes, as I've already said, I can't find the difference between redux and context api in the code.
Redux re-renders only components that are used the states using useSelector, not useDispatch ,but Context API re-renders all components that are consumed the states using useContext and dispatch.
I don't understand about it.
I tested the following project.

https://www.codehousegroup.com/insight-and-inspiration/tech-stream/using-redux-and-context-api#:~:text=Context%20API%20is%20easy%20to,creating%20unnecessary%20work%20and%20complexity.

Comment: This is a hard question. IMHO, redux is a bit global, at least how everyone used it, so it normally applies to the entire app. However context is really created for local (not trivial) scope of branch of components tree. For example, you are developing a Table, and you'd like to share all table stuff inside children. Hope this short answer helps. My two cents, nothing should be made literal GLOBAL.

Comment: @windmaomao - this is not a hard question. redux uses the context api to deliver a value (the store, never* changes), but not the way that most people use context in non-redux implementations (state/props inside the provider that change often)

Comment: @CoryR - I encourage you to take a look at the internals of `react-redux`. It's not that complicated. A [Provider](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js) makes a `store` available via context. `connect`/`useSelector` subscribe to that `store` and, effectively, update local state variables (causing components to re-render) when the values those subscribers are interested in the state contained inside the store change.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT:

This answer is still conceptually valid, but the implementation details have changed, rather significantly between v7 and v8. The github link points to v7, but all the high level details remain the same.

It's because of how the state is encapsulated. In `react-redux`, state is encapsulated inside a `store`. When you pass the store to `Provider` in `react-redux` - you are using the Context API (see [this in react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v7.1.1/src/components/Provider.js)) but here's the kicker - the redux context **never changes** (in 99% of implementations anyway). So the Consumers of the Redux context will never re-render the way a regular `context` consumer would (because the value supplied by the context never changes).

So how the heck does redux cause react components to re-render then?

A component `subscribe`'s to the store that is delivered via the Redux context and it (let's just talk about the `useSelector` hook - connect HOC works the same, though) set's it's own `state` variable. When the redux store's state updates (actions, dispatch, you know), the store calls any subscribers with the new state. If the value subscribed (or selected from the state) is the same as the previous value, then redux **doesn't update the state variable in the hook or HOC** - check out [this file](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v7.1.1/src/hooks/useSelector.js#L33) and look for `forceRender`.

This is different from the Context API because the source of data of the Context API (in most typical use cases) are state variables in the Provider (or props from above). Whenever the values given to context change, consumers re-render. This is **fundamentally different** than the way `react-redux` works because, as stated above, the value given to the `react-redux` context **never changes** (it's the store, remember?)

**tldr** in `react-redux` the context provided by the redux provider is a `store` and **never changes**. In typical non-redux context API use cases, the value supplied by context itself changes.

This can be very confusing, ask lots of questions to help me improve my answer!

EDIT: You made a comment about `useDispatch` not resulting in re-renders. This is because [from the docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch):

> The dispatch function reference will be stable as long as the same store > instance is being passed to the <Provider>.

i.e. `useDispatch` **never changes** (as long as the store doesn't change, 99% of the time it won't because people are encouraged to design apps with a single non-changing store)

Comment: Thank you, Adam.
I understood why context API re-renders all consumers and learned very much from you.